# Cannot get values from javascript object during onclick (returns undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK So I have a variable `eventMap` which is a JavaScript Object that contains objects within itself.

I have an onclick function as shown:

```
        if (localStorage.cal) {
            var dat = JSON.parse(localStorage.cal);
            console.log(dat);
            eventMap = dat.map; 
            eventList = dat.list;
        }
        $(delAppearance).on('click', function(){
            if (lastKey && eventMap[lastKey]) {
              var e = eventMap[lastKey];
              eventList[lastKey] = undefined;
              delete eventList[lastKey];
              calObj.removeEvents(function(event){
                return new Date(event.date).toUTCString() == moment(lastKey)._d.toUTCString();

              });
              localStorage.cal = JSON.stringify({list:eventList, map:eventMap});
              lastKey = null;
              $(delAppearance).hide();
            }
        });
```

So Last Key is currently set to `06/20/2017`. There is a record inside `eventMap` for `06/20/2017` (look at the image below); For some reason when I try to access`eventMap[lastKey]` i get `undefined` and i cannot enter the function (look at `if(lastKey && eventMap[lastKey])`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

**UPDATE**

So it looks like its coming from this:

```
    var calClick = function(target){
        clearState();
        var d = new Date(target.date._d);
        var prettyDate = ((d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear());
        var hr = new Date().getHours();
        var min = new Date().getMinutes();
        $(aDate).val(prettyDate);
        var s;
        console.log(target);
        if (s = eventMap[prettyDate]) {
          lastKey = prettyDate;
          $(delAppearance).show();
          setCurrentState(s);
        }

    }
```

It never reaches the lastKey here. It seems like the same issue though. I must be accessing the eventMap the wrong way.

Comment: Where are you assigning eventMap to the map object?

Comment: @mjw fixed question

Comment: Is last key defined?

Comment: @MBurnham I think it has to do with lastKey ill post code.

Comment: How does lastKey get its value? In particular, is it assigned a value from  inside data.map?

Comment: updated question see bototm

Comment: i think it has to do wtih `target` looking now

Comment: @jkushner that confirms my suspicions. Check my answer below. You need to make sure you assign it an object that is already in the dictionary, not a new one that looks like the one in the dictionary :-)

Comment: @RodolfoGrave can you please provide code samples? I'm having difficutly grasping what you are saying.

Comment: @RodolfoGrave But when I do console.log(eventMap) it shows the object

Comment: I updated my response with some code. If you print the eventMap you will see "an object" that looks the same as your key, but is in fact different. They clue is in the fact that you use "new" to create the instance you use as the key. That works in many other languages, but unfortunately not in JavaScript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146892/discussion-between-rodolfo-grave-and-jkushner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hash codes in JavaScript are not similar to Java or C#. Each object has its own hash key and there is no consistency with equality.

When you parse the JSON into eventMap, you are creating an instance of an object "06/20/2017" (not sure what the type is from your code, perhaps a Date?).

When you are trying to access eventList[lastKey] you are using ***another*** instance of an object that also looks like "06/20/2017".

Code is worth more than a thousand words:

```
let d1 = new Date(2017, 5, 20);
let d2 = new Date(2017, 5, 20);
// d1 and d2 are different instances. even though they look the same.

let mapObject = {};
mapObject[d1] = "some value";
console.debug(mapObject[d1]); // Will print 'some value'
console.debug(mapObject[d2]); // Will print null

d2 = d1; // Now let's make d2 the same instance as d1
console.debug(mapObject[d2]); // Will now print the *expected* 'some value'
```

If you want to use another instance to access the Map you'll need to implement an *identity map* to make sure you always return the same instance when the objects are "equal" according to your definition or "equal".

Alternatively, you can make sure you assign the original object to *lastKey* instead of assigning a new instance.

I recommend the latter.

Comment: But when I do console.log(eventMap) it shows the object